# How to append two lists in order into a text file?

Tags: python, append

Say I have two lists:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]

b = [hello, how, iz, life]
```

How can I make a new list `c` that takes each element in list `a` and matches it in order to an element in list `b`? I want the text file to look something like this:

```
1 hello
2 how
3 iz
4 life
```

I attempted `c.append(a,b)`, but I got the following error:

```
TypeError: list.append() takes exactly one argument (2 given)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]

b = ["hello", "how", "iz", "life"]


c = zip(a,b)

with open("sample.txt", 'w') as outfile:
    for elem in c:
        outfile.write(str(elem[0]) + " " + elem[1] +"\n")
```

This will output:

```
1 hello
2 how
3 iz
4 life
```

to a file called sample.txt.

**Edit**:
Kelly makes a great point you can just simplify the line as `print(*elem, file=outfile)`. I looked at the [docs for print](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) and I was surprised to find that the print function defines a separator for elements given in the *objects argument and ends the line with a newline through default arguments, which provides us with the same desired output.

Comment: @facialrecognition If you want to list each letter with its position in the string, you could try ```s = "Hello" ; b = [i for i in range(len(s))] ; c = zip(b,s) ; print(list(c))``` (all on one line because no formatting for comments - replying to deleted comment).

Comment: I'd much prefer `print(*elem, file=outfile)`. At the very least, don't call the *output* file `infile` :-)

Comment: *"separates elements given in the first argument"* - Not really. The `*` unpacks the pair into *two* arguments. That happens before calling the `print` functon, which doesn't even know that that happened.